# block script debugging for wpf browser control

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I have used browser control for my WPF browser application.I want to disable the script error message.Please let me know exactly as I am very new to this application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer other than disabling script message on advance tab of internet option.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the WPF `WebBrowser` did not implement this property as in the 2.0 control.

Your best bet is to use a `WindowsFormsHost` in your WPF application and use the 2.0's `WebBrowser` property: `SuppressScriptErrors`. Even then, you will need the application to be full trust in order to do this.

Not what one would call ideal, but it's pretty much the only option currently.